# Sort the result from a PyMongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB query as follows :

```
data =  db.collection.aggregate([{"$match":{"created_at":{"$gte":start,"$lt":end}}},{"$group":{"_id":"$stage","count":{"$sum":1}}},{"$match":{"count":{"$gt":m{u'count': 296, u'_id': u'10.57.72.93'}
```

Which results in the following output:

```
{u'count': 230, u'_id': u'111.11.111.111'}
{u'count': 2240, u'_id': u'111.11.11.11'}
```

I am trying to sort the output by the 'count' column:

```
data.sort('count',  pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

...but I am getting the following error:

```
'CommandCursor' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `$sort` as shown in [Aggregation example](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-examples):

```
from bson.son import SON

data =  db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$match":{"created_at":{"$gte":start,"$lt":end}}},
    {"$group":{"_id":"$stage","count":{"$sum":1}}},
    {"$match":{"count": ... }},
    {"$sort": SON([("count", -1)])}  # <---
])
```

---

alternative general solution: use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) with custom key function:

```
data =  db.collection.aggregate(...)
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x['count'], reverse=True)
```

Comment: I get an error stating name 'SON' is not defined but the other alternative works perfect

Comment: @Prakash, Did you import it as shown in the first line of the code?

Comment: Thanks it worked but this one also worked : {"$sort":{"count": -1}} - is there any difference in between them?

Comment: @Prakash, Using `$sort ..` , sorting is done by mongdb side, while using `sorted` sort is done Python side.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [`$sort`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework). Check [Mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) also.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation pipelines have a [`$sort`](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html#aggregation-framework) pipeline stage:

```
data =  db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$match":{"created_at":{"$gte":start,"$lt":end} }},
   { "$group":{ "_id":"$stage","count":{"$sum":1} }},
   { "$match":{
       "count":{  "$gt": 296 }  # query trimmed because your question listing is incomplete
   }},
   { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }   # Actual sort stage
])
```

The other `.sort()` method is for a "cursor" which is different from what the aggregation pipeline does.